# "To order delivery" or "to order a delivery"?

Tags: articles

What's the correct form? A native English speaker told me it should be "to order a delivery."

However, "to order delivery" has more hits on Google Books.

Example sentence:

> Speaking of food, could you order (a) delivery? I'm still hungry.

Another similar example (I think):

> I don't have (an) appetite for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be:

> Speaking of food, could you order a delivery.

where *delivery* is a noun. Or:

> Speaking of food, could you order delivery (pizza).

where *delivery* is an adjective modifying an unspoken noun.

But this doesn't apply to your second example, unless you can come up with an example using *appetite* as an adjective modifying a noun not needing an article. So as written (an) is needed.